# how do I extend virtual key codes in the windows API (Win32)?

Tags: windows, winapi, keycode, virtual-keyboard, scancodes

I want to create a new virtual key code in the windows API that I can assign scan codes to and read with GetKeyState but I cannot find a way to extend the enumeration.

I have tried using "unknown" virtual key codes in sharpkeys but some applications end up registering those virtual keys rendering my bindings obsolete.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

Answer (score 0):

Those key codes are just `#define`s, not an enumeration.

You can define your own, of course. But how do you plan to use them? What would make them a `virtual key`? Are you writing a keyboard driver?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm writing a mouse keys program in Rust and I need the number pad to not type in values by default but I still need to handle the key press. using the event message system prevents me from getting n key rollover as I can only process one message at a time for some reason. I have had success using unused key bindings and the win32 api getkeystate for virtual keys but some non-UWP applications try to use these bindings for some reason and then my mouse key fails.

Comment: Did you try `NumLock` key?

Comment: I want to be able to switch to arrow mode with numlock. Also that would cause arrow movement with mouse keys.

Comment: @BotsFab "*I need the number pad to not type in values by default but I still need to handle the key press*" - use a `WH_KEYBOARD/_LL` hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` to detect and discard key strokes before Windows dispatches them to apps for processing.

Comment: Thanks I'll go back to that attempt and review further. Is that lower level than GetKeyState? I have tried something similar (almost exactly) but don't get n key rollover (simultaneous key presses) unless I use GetKeyState.

Comment: That still doesn't allow n key rollover. It seems to have to do with events further or earlier in the hook chain after I set a hook with SetWindowsHookEx (but this is kind of a guess since I can't view the hook chain in code or otherwise with my current knowledge). Blocking the hook chain also doesn't resolve this and still doesn't allow n key rollover. The only thing I've gotten to work is GetKeyState and rebinding the virtual key codes to values that *usually* don't do anything. I really wish Microsoft's api was more extensible or I knew more.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define new virtual key codes.  They are fixed values defined inside the OS that keyboard drivers must follow.  Only Microsoft can define new key codes.